# How to convert a list of sentences in a single text?

Tags: python, nlp

I have an list of sentences like this:

```
 ['Circula hoje o caderno especial "Folha Rock". Ele traz todas as informações para quem vai ao 
   M2.000 Summer Concerts, que começa hoje, e ao Hollywood Rock, a partir do dia 14. Mais de 30 
   bandas se apresentam nos dois festivais. O reggae domina a primeira noite do M2.000.',
  'O delegado Nélson Guimarães, que apura a morte do sindicalista Oswaldo Cruz Júnior, não descarta 
  "motivações políticas" para o crime. O enterro foi marcado pela disputa da sucessão. Um grupo 
   apoiou o irmão de Oswaldo. Outro quer Cícero Bezerra da Silva, ligado a José Benedito de Souza, 
   suspeito do crime que está foragido. Brasil']
```

And i need that list like this:

```
  ['Circula hoje o caderno especial "Folha Rock". Ele traz todas as informações para quem vai ao 
   M2.000 Summer Concerts, que começa hoje, e ao Hollywood Rock, a partir do dia 14. Mais de 30 
   bandas se apresentam nos dois festivais. O reggae domina a primeira noite do M2.000.
   O delegado Nélson Guimarães, que apura a morte do sindicalista Oswaldo Cruz Júnior, não descarta 
  "motivações políticas" para o crime. O enterro foi marcado pela disputa da sucessão. Um grupo 
   apoiou o irmão de Oswaldo. Outro quer Cícero Bezerra da Silva, ligado a José Benedito de Souza, 
   suspeito do crime que está foragido. Brasil']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to convert all elements of a list into a single string right ?

This might help you.
it will give you a single string variable

```
yourlist = ['Circula hoje o caderno especial "Folha Rock". Ele traz todas as informações para quem vai ao M2.000 Summer Concerts, que começa hoje, e ao Hollywood Rock, a partir do dia 14. Mais de 30 bandas se apresentam nos dois festivais. O reggae domina a primeira noite do M2.000.',
  'O delegado Nélson Guimarães, que apura a morte do sindicalista Oswaldo Cruz Júnior, não descarta"motivações políticas" para o crime. O enterro foi marcado pela disputa da sucessão. Um grupo apoiou o irmão de Oswaldo. Outro quer Cícero Bezerra da Silva, ligado a José Benedito de Souza, suspeito do crime que está foragido. Brasil']
str = ""
for x in yourlist:
  str = str + x

print(str)
```

Answer (score 1):

you can do

```py
yourlistname = ['Circula hoje o caderno especial "Folha Rock". Ele traz todas as informações para quem vai ao 
   M2.000 Summer Concerts, que começa hoje, e ao Hollywood Rock, a partir do dia 14. Mais de 30 
   bandas se apresentam nos dois festivais. O reggae domina a primeira noite do M2.000.',
  'O delegado Nélson Guimarães, que apura a morte do sindicalista Oswaldo Cruz Júnior, não descarta 
  "motivações políticas" para o crime. O enterro foi marcado pela disputa da sucessão. Um grupo 
   apoiou o irmão de Oswaldo. Outro quer Cícero Bezerra da Silva, ligado a José Benedito de Souza, 
   suspeito do crime que está foragido. Brasil']

output = '\n'.join(yourlistname)
```

this will give you what you want

you can chose any seperator other than `\n`

Comment: Thanks! I do it but the words are cut in the final of the sentence, you know how to fix this ?

Comment: do you mean the " [ " and "]" are cutting

Answer (score 0):

I think this will help you:

```
s = ['My name is', 'XYZ', 'I am from X'] 
sen = ' '.join([i for i in s])
sen
```

> 'My name is XYZ I am from X'